# Sending emails from AWS SES slow in Spring Boot take arounf 300ms to send one email

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ses

is AWS ses is slow in spring boot ? I used python and it takes 0.3 ms to send the email while spring boot is taking 300ms for sending one email.

Below is the python code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import time
# Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = " <info@researchkernel.org>"
# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = "prakritidevverma@gmail.com"
# Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
# set, comment the following variable, and the 
# ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET argument below.
CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"
# If necessary, replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "iimjobs.com - Your Personalized Jobfeed"
# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
BODY_TEXT = """"""
# The HTML body of the email.
BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>
  <p>This email was sent with
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>
      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>
      <p>Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries of our body spreading all over in Delhi. One day I had to go to railway station to receive my uncle. I had to reach there by 9.30 a.m. knowing the irregularity of D.T.C. bus service; I left my home at 7.30 a.m. and reached the bus stop. There was a long queue. Everybody was waiting for the bus but the buses were passing one after another without stopping. I kept waiting for about an hour. I was feeling very restless and I was afraid that I might not be able to reach the station in time. It was 8.45. Luckily a bus stopped just in front of me. It was overcrowded but somehow I managed to get into the bus. Some passengers were hanging on the footboard, so there was no question of getting a seat. It was very uncomfortable. We were feeling suffocated. All of a sudden, an old man declared that his pocket had been picked. He accused the man standing beside him. The young man took a knife out of his pocket and waved it in the air. No body dared to catch him. I thanked God when the bus stopped at the railway station. I reached there just in time.</P>
      <p>Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries of our body spreading all over in Delhi. One day I had to go to railway station to receive my uncle. I had to reach there by 9.30 a.m. knowing the irregularity of D.T.C. bus service; I left my home at 7.30 a.m. and reached the bus stop. There was a long queue. Everybody was waiting for the bus but the buses were passing one after another without stopping. I kept waiting for about an hour. I was feeling very restless and I was afraid that I might not be able to reach the station in time. It was 8.45. Luckily a bus stopped just in front of me. It was overcrowded but somehow I managed to get into the bus. Some passengers were hanging on the footboard, so there was no question of getting a seat. It was very uncomfortable. We were feeling suffocated. All of a sudden, an old man declared that his pocket had been picked. He accused the man standing beside him. The young man took a knife out of his pocket and waved it in the air. No body dared to catch him. I thanked God when the bus stopped at the railway station. I reached there just in time.</p>
</body>
</html>
            """
# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"
# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)
start = time.time()
# Try to send the email.
try:
    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
        # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        # following line
        # ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
end = time.time()
print("time taken : SES : "+ end-start)
```

I'm using https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/tree/master/aws/springcloudses

for sending emails.

I'm not sure why is that. can anyone help ?

Comment: You're using Python code in a Java/Spring-Boot application?

Comment: that is because you are using smtp proto instead of ses api. btw, what forces you to follow third-party tutorials instead of official ones? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html

Answer (score 3):

To send emails using SES in a Spring BOOT app, use the **SES Java V2** API (the link in your comment uses V1).

Specifically use the [SesClient client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ses/SesClient.html). This is the V2 service client for SES.

Always look at the new Code Lib for latest code examples:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html

You will find many AWS Service specific code examples (in all SDK supported programming languages) in this guide along with many AWS Dev tutorial, such as this one that shows you how to build a Spring BOOT app that uses multiple services, that includes SES.

[Detect objects in images with Amazon Rekognition using an AWS SDK
PDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_java_2_topic.html)

As stated in a comment above -- always look at official AWS Docs over 3rd party.